# How to migrate specific files from Mercurial to gitlab with commit history?

Tags: git, gitlab, repository, mercurial

I have a case to migrate only one folder from Mercurial(Hg) to Gitlab (not the entire repository) with its history.

I came across hg-fast-export but I am not sure if we can export only a few files to GitLab. If yes suggest to me how to do this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Migrate entire repository and then use `git filter-repo` to remove everything except the required folder.

Comment: yeah, I thought of it. But I am doing this stage by stage. After two months, I will move another folder to the same dest Gitlab repo. At that time also, I need to migrate entire repo and use filter-repo once again rite?

Comment: Another folder from the same Mercurial source? Why not migrate them both now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A good way to do this would be to use [`hg convert` with the `filemap`](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/ConvertExtension#A--filemap) option to first create a second temporary Mercurial repository which contains only the folder your are interested in, and then import just that to Gitlab.

> `Convert` can also **filter** or rename files during conversion, when you
> supply it a mapping via the `--filemap` option.
>
> The filemap is a file that specifies which files are to be included,
> renamed, or omitted. By default all files are included (empty filemap
> means include everything).
>
> Each line can contain one of the following directives:
>
> include path/to/file
>
> exclude path/to/file
>
> rename from/file to/file

Note that when you use convert it produces an entirely new repository that is not "related" to the original. So changeset IDs will be different. Seems like this won't cause any harm for what you are doing.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I was trying this `hg convert --filemap file.txt /path/to/source/repo /path/to/destination/repo', once the command was executed. it is started scanning and fetching till the first changeset once it is completed I couldn't see any changes in the destination repo, only the empty repo is created. Am I missing some thing here?

Comment: For reference, in file.txt I am having include "path/to/myfile"

Comment: There is probably something a little bit wrong with the include path. Case sensitivity? Whitespace?

Comment: If you edit the question with more specifics of the folder structure and the filemap text maybe we can spot something useful.

Comment: Yeah, I made mistake in giving the file map. Then I rerun the hg convert, but still, the new repo is empty. From some StackOverflow answers, I figured out that I need to execute `hg update` but after that, I am getting this error "abort: 00manifest@e7b4c42161b0551f537ecfb371b35e4c8ede4d6e: no node". Any idea?

Comment: When you say the repo is "empty" I'm not sure what you mean. If there are changesets you may still need to run hg update to get files in your local working directory. But if there are no changesets at all then the filemap probably was wrong and everything was excluded.

Comment: yes, there are changesets, using the hg log I can see that. But I can't update my working directory using "hg update". It is throwing an error like this "abort: 00manifest@e7b4c42161b0551f537ecfb371b35e4c8ede4d6e: no node" when I am giving hg update.

Comment: That's a very strange error, I'm afraid I've never encountered that. As a guess, the original repo may have had something wrong with it and now the remaining filtered history in the second one has a problem. You might try `hg verify` in the original and/or the copy and see if that helps.   https://wiki.mercurial-scm.org/RepositoryCorruption

Answer (score 1):

A clean way to do it would be to have folder1 for your mercurial repo and folder2 for your git repo. You could get all the revision hashes in your Mercurial repo and then:

- for each commit hash

  - check out that hash in folder1
  - override any files of your interest at folder2 with the content of folder1
  - commit

This can be automatized into a command-line bash script.